# Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, gpu

How can I fix this error in Ubuntu 20.04?

```
(base) mona@mona:~/research/animal_pose$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
(base) mona@mona:~/research/animal_pose$ nvidia-smi
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch
```

Answer (score 0):

Very strange but restarting the system faded away the error. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/+bug/1888440

Comment: Perhaps a system upgrade in the background had likely modified the Nvidia driver library. Therefore, requiring the system to restart for the driver to function correctly.